# How in Coq to use mod arithmetic (specifically Zplus_mod theorem) for natural numbers?

Tags: logic, coq, modulo, coq-tactic

I want to apply the [library](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.ZArith.Zdiv.html) theorem:

```
Theorem Zplus_mod: forall a b n, (a + b) mod n = (a mod n + b mod n) mod n.
```

where `a b n` are expected to have the type `Z`.

I have a subexpression `(a + b) mod 3` in my goal, with `a b : nat`.

`rewrite Zplus_mod` gives an error `Found no subterm matching`

`rewrite Zplus_mod with (a := a)` gives an error `"a" has type "nat" while it is expected to have type "Z".`

Since natural numbers are also integers, **how to use Zplus_mod theorem for nat arguments**?

Comment: For a quick answer to this question, we need to know what are exactly the modules you have required and imported.  So a minimal working example would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply this theorem, because the notation `mod` refers to a function on natural numbers `Nat.modulo` in a context where you are using natural numbers, while the notation `mod` refers to `Z.modulo` when you are referring to integers of type `Z`.

Using the `Search` command ou can search specifically for theorems about `Nat.modulo` and `(_ + _)%nat` and you will see that some existing theorems are actually close to your needs (`Nat.add_mod_idemp_l` and `Nat.add_mod_idemp_r`).

You can also look for a theorem that links `Z.modulo` and `Nat.modulo`.  This gives `mod_Zmod`.  But this forces you to work in the type of integers:

```
Require Import Arith ZArith.

Search Z.modulo Nat.modulo.

 (* The answer is :  
    mod_Zmod: forall n m, m <> 0 -> Z.of_nat (n mod m) = 
       (Z.of_nat n mod Z.of_nat m)%Z  *)
```

One way out is to find a theorem that tells you that the function `Z.of_nat` is injective.  I found it by typing the following command.

```
Search Z.of_nat "inj".
```

In the long list that was produced, the relevant theorem is `Nat2Z.inj`, you
then need to show how `Z.of_nat` interacts with all of the operators involved.  Most of these theorems require `n` to be non-zero, so I add this as a condition.  Here is the example.

```
Lemma example (a b n : nat) : 
   n <> 0 -> (a + b) mod n = (a mod n + b mod n) mod n.
Proof.
intro nn0.
apply Nat2Z.inj.
rewrite !mod_Zmod; auto.
rewrite !Nat2Z.inj_add.
rewrite !mod_Zmod; auto.
rewrite Zplus_mod.
easy.
Qed.
```

This answers your question, but frankly, I believe you would be better off using the lemmas `Nat.add_mod_idemp_l` and `Nat.add_mod_idemp_r`.